# How to connect local SQL Server machine in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have made a sample shiny app that gets connected with the SQL Server running on my local host. I have created a free account in shinyapps.io and when I tried to deploy to it, I am getting the error "failed to load from server"

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(RMySQL)
library(lubridate)
library(DBI)


con_iris <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "iris_db",
  host = "localhost",
  username = "XXXX",
  password = "XXXXXX"
)



ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  #fluid page for dynamically adapting to screens of different resolutions.
  titlePanel("Iris Dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select", label = h5("select species"),choices = c("setosa"=1, "Vericolor"=2, "virginica"=3), 
                  selected = 1)
                ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("data")
    )
  )
))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #referring output distPlot in ui.r as output$distPlot
  output$data <- renderText({
      query<-paste0("select * from iris where Species= '", input$select , "'", sep='')
      species<-dbGetQuery(con_iris, query)
      })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Can anyone help me like what are all the procedural changes that needs to be done in the code/shinyapps.io account....to deploy the shiny app and fetch data from the sql server which is hosted locally in my machine...because i couldn't any proper steps to connect with my local server...reallly need help in this guys...!!!

Comment: This depends whether your computer has a publicly accessible IP address or if you are behind a router. Independent of that, I can only strongly advice against making the SQL Server accessible from the internet, which is what you would have to do. Can’t you transfer the data into a SQLite database and include that in the shiny app?

Comment: Yeah that i can transfer the SQL server database to SQLite but the problem,the sql server populates new data every 10 mins once and from that data i updating the charts in the shiny app....so i have done it locally but i dont know which option to go for for deploying it shinyapps.io/shiny server pro...??can you suggest....or is there any other solution for this...??

Comment: It sounds like you really want to set up your own shiny server. Pro or community depends on how secure you want to keep your data...

Comment: yeah but can you tell for time being is there way to connect local server to shinyapps.io..??

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197727/connect-sql-server-2005-2008-over-internet and multiple similar questions.