# Disconnected from server while deploying shiny dashboard in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am getting error while deploying shinydashboard in shinyapps.io.
Here is the logs:[image]

connection code:

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='XXXXX',
              password='XXXXXXXX', dbname='XXXXXX',
              host='XXX.XX.X.XXX', port=3306)
```

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The database is in cloud or in your local?

Comment: I am local database.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of shinyapps.io. This can help you...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002990/how-to-connect-local-sql-server-machine-in-shinyapps-io

Comment: I aslo tried with RSQLite library, but failed to deploy.

Comment: From Local You need to build the Server which can be connected by shinyapps.io that means making as Public IP which might concern a security issue.You better think about a complete Secure Arch for your APP.